# C# парсинг строки и конвертация в double

Tags: c#, база-данных, парсер, double, конвертация

Строка была получена таким образом:

```
FRAX.Text = 
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lbbmi").InnerText;
```

В текст-бокс загружается `"BMI: 22.2"`, однако в БД надо сохранить в типе `double`.

Comment: Double.Parse(FRAX.Text.Split(new String[] {": "}, SplitOptions.None)[1])

Answer (score 2):

```
double dbVal = Double.Parse(FRAX.Text.Split(':')[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Здесь:

`FRAX.Text.Split(':')[1]` разделяет строку на массив по разделителю ":" и берётся вторая его часть (индексация с нуля).

`Double.Parse` полученное выражение " 22.2" уже парсится в double

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` для избежания конфликтов с точкой. 
Дело в том, что в английском для разделения дробной части используется точка, а в русском запятая. Обозначение культуры необходимо для избежания подобных конфликтов.

Comment: Лучше не заменять точку на запятую, а использовать инвариантную культуру. ```Double.Parse("22.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)```

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо. знал про это, но забыл реализацию.. пожалуй исправлю ответ)

Comment: исправили бы тогда до конца, а то теперь непонятно причем тут Replace

Comment: @rdorn извиняюсь, забылся)